SQL Problem : Use min and max in chronological groups
I would like to know if it is possible to group ONLY in chronological order and display the min and max according to the groups.
An example :



TYPE
Start_dath
End_dath




TL1
01/01
31/01


TL1
01/02
29/02


TL2
01/03
31/03


TL1
01/04
30/04



I would like to have this result in SQL :



TYPE
Start_dath
End_dath




TL1
01/01
29/02


TL2
01/03
31/03


TL1
01/04
30/04



select TYPE, MIN(Start_dath), MAX(End_dath)
from table
group by TYPE

Have you ever used window functions or is there a reason you can't use them? Also what version of SQL are you using? Also this seems to be easy to do using basic grouping. If you were using tsql you could use min() over() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

So in other terms: You want to merge ajoining groups with the same type? Can it there be gaps in the timeline or overlapping periods? If yes, what would be the expected result then? For instance  if you only had the following two rows: TL1|01/01|31/01 and TL1|01/03|31/03? Should they be merged or keep separated?

@derpirscher Yes, I want to merge groups of the same type only if there is no change in the "type" label in chronological order. Periods cannot overlap. Your example doesn't exist in my case

Thanks for your reply, I'll have a look at your documentation on the feasibility of my problem. I'm currently using POSTGRESQL. I'm a beginner so I don't know T-SQL, so I'll look into it. @Monofuse

What does "01/04" mean for you? April 1st or January 4th? Please use ISO dates for easy understanding (as in 2020-04-01).

You have a gaps and islands problem here, it can be resolved by calculating the difference between row numbers.
Assuming the original table is ordered by Start_dath (if there is another column you are using for ordering, you should use it in the ORDER BY clauses instead):
SELECT TYPE, MIN(Start_dath), MAX(End_dath)
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_dath ) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY Start_dath ) AS grp
  FROM mytable
) AS S
GROUP BY grp, TYPE

Demo here

I think your wrong, but just because the original comment doesn't give enough info
